# ViewBag.Title displaying html tags in browser tab for web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, tabs, viewbag

**Action:** I am pulling a string from a resource file into a cshtml view. After concatenating bold tags to the string I am using the 'Html.Raw' function to assign this string to ViewBag.Title.

**Result:** In the web page the string correctly displays in bold font. However, in the browser page tab the html mark up has not been parsed and the bold tags can be seen. This is the code I am using:

```
ViewBag.Title = Html.Raw("<b>" + ResourceFile.MyString + "</b>");
```

I am confused because in one location the bold tags are being correctly parsed and in another they are not, even though source of the string is the same in both cases.

Any thought or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Browser tabs in any browser don't support any kind of markup to my knowledge. Just set it to a naked string.

Comment: I tried setting it to a naked string and then placing the bold tags in the .cshtml file instead however this doesn't work. The VewBag.Title ends up just getting rendered as normal text on the page as opposed to being rendered in the correct position for a title.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `ViewBag.Title` to display anything in the view. It's usually set in the view for use in the shared `_Layout.cshtml` file. But in the view itself, you should be able to just use text (e.g. `<h2>My Little Pony Characters</h2>`). Unless you're creating a shared view?

Comment: Thank you, your last comment sparked the solution for me. I wasn't paying attention to the Viewbag call being made in _Layout.cshtml. That's where I needed to be applying by bold tags. Much appreciated!